# Why did הַר הַזֵּיתִים become a place of burial

Tags: history, cemetery-grave, yerushalayim-jerusalem

I am wondering if there was any particular reason that [הַר הַזֵּיתִים](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_of_olives) was chosen to become a place of burial. Is there?

Comment: http://www.shemayisrael.co.il/yomtov/sukkot/willow.htm see the story "Blemished Service"